# How to filter the list of countries by its first letter while search in ui-select using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-ui-select

[image]

How can i search the word by filtering the list by its first letter?

```
 <td class="country-selection-cell">
         <ui-select multiple ng-disabled="service.serviceName === null" ng-model="service.countries" close-on-select="false" ng-change="vm.checkIfDuplicatesExist(newServiceWithCountriesForm)"
                ng-attr-title="{{service.serviceName === null?'Please select a service first':'Choose countries'}}" ng-required="true">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select countries...">
                     {{$item}}
                </ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="country in vm.countries | filter:$select.search track by $index" position='down'>
                  {{country}}
                </ui-select-choices>
         </ui-select>
 </td>
```

Comment: where is your search ?

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez ui-select tag works as the search dropdown with the list of items to be selected from them

Comment: then use your ng-model as filter.  filter : service.countries

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez No...i tried...that doesn't work....i want the search filter should happen for the first letter of the words from the list.....example:if i search for 'i' in search box then the words starting from 'i' should group under dropdown

Comment: then you should add search box. your question is so confusing.

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez sorry for the confusion...i have edited my question....from the above image added..for now,from ui-select directive i have got a search box by itself....when i have entered 'i' it filters through the list and groups all the words which contains letter 'i'.....instead,i want it to group only the words with starting letter as 'i'...